# In javascript I have passed the object to ejs file, but it still says that object is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, associations, ejs

This is Colt Steele's yelp camp project. I'm stuck at creating comments, i always got this warning ***Cannot read property 'name' of null*** .
This is my app.js file

```js
app.get('/campgrounds/:id', function(req, res){
//  find campground with the provided ID
 Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate('comments').exec(function(err, foundCampground){
  if(err){
   console.log(err);
  } else {
   console.log(foundCampground)
   res.render('show', {campground: foundCampground});
  }
 });
});
```

and this is the show.ejs file

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<h1>
    <%= campground.name %>
</h1>
<img src='<%= campground.image %>'>
<p><%= campground.description %></p>

<% campground.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <p><%= comment.author %> - <%= comment.text %></p>
<% })%>
<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

Can somebody help me whats wrong with my code? if i checked in database, campground already has data on it

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(foundCampground)`?

Comment: what'ts the output of `foundCampground` ?

Comment: It says it's undefined

Comment: Are the campgrounds in the same folder or in a subfolder called **campgrounds**?

Answer (score 0):

There could be problems of your campground.comments json data.

```
const foundCampground = {
            name : 'test',
            description:'desc test',
            image : 'test.jpg',
            comments: [
                {
                    author:"product1",
                    text : "text1"
                },
                {
                    author:"product2",
                    text : "text2"
                }
            ]
        }
res.render('show',{campground:foundCampground})
```

Try with this static json & if its working properly, then check with your json data which is coming from database. Always try to work with **Static data** if you are facing issue related to data.

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered same problem. In my case, I dropped all my comments from the collections named ' campground'. Please check your database for the comments. You can do this, in case you are using mongodb,
    ```

```
show dbs
use yelp_camp // name of your db
show collections
```

(You might notice your 'campground' collection as empty)
Now refresh your webpage and you will notice that your '/campgrounds/' webpage doesn't have any campgrounds, thus making the campground object == null.